# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in overwritten section blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this in my layoutblade.php :

```
@section('content')
<h2>Title of the site</h2>
<p>other content</p>
    {{ $myVariable }}
@show
```

I have this in my test.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
    other content
@endsection
```

but, in this view, I have undefined variable, it overwritten the view, but not the variable, help me.

Comment: do you have undefined variable in test.blade.php?

Comment: indeed, when i call this view.

Comment: what are you doing in your layout. the layout should be define like this @yield('content')

Comment: i have some views, but i want to overwrite this section in other view.

Comment: but, I can't do this, beacause is rendering this variable without do reference it

Answer (score 0):

```
//layout

@yield('content')



//test.blade.php

    @extends('layout')
    @section('content')
       {{ $myVariable }}
        other content
    @endsection
```

then your `{{ $myVariable }}` should be outputted from your controller like this:

```
$data['myVariable']='';

return view('test',$data)
```

Comment: but, i want to set default value in layout

Comment: to set default value in your layout output the {{ $myVariable }} on the layout using $data['myVariable']='';

Comment: i change the question, I want to overwrite this content, if is not specified, set as default of the layout.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

on your controller you can do something like this:

```
if($myVariable==''){
  $data['myVariable']==''
  rerurn view('blade', $data)
}
else{

  $data['myVariable']== //load data to the variable
  rerurn view('blade', $data)
}
```

Comment: what happend with the rest of the html tags?? i don´t want just the variable